# Internationalization with cocos2d-x Android

Tags: android, internationalization, cocos2d-x

I am new to Cocos2D-X and I am developing an android application with eclipse and cocos2d-x. I want it to be multilingual (Internationalization).

so I use the android function: getString (R.string.blabla) to create my menu in my first scene (CCLayer class).

I get the following error message: "The method getString (int) is undefined for the type MenuLayer"

I also tried: Resources.getSystem () getString (R.string.blabla) but without success..

I searched a lot on google etc, but I have not found a solution suitable for android.

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the link:

https://github.com/Vorren/Localization

It's my personal little snippet that I use in my projects.